# Adding to a SQL database from PHP Script. No errors and looks successful but doesn't insert

Tags: php, mysql

Currently working with a php script and a sql database. Everything seems like it's working okay and even when echoing the username at the end it seems to be successful. When looking further into the insertion in the database the row was not inserted. There is no error message and the insert statement reflects the columns exactly... Any ideas?

```
<?php
$db_name = "animator"; // Database name
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not connect to Database" .mysql_error());

$username  = $_POST['fname'];
$passwords = $_POST['pass'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];

mysql_query($link,"INSERT INTO 'account'('username', 'passwords', 'email') VALUES 
($username , $passwords , $email)");

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

****UPDATE***********
Thank you so much for everyones response. I was finally able to get it working with another technique I found.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
$db_name = "animator"; // Database name
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not connect to Database" .mysql_error());

$username = $_POST['fname'];
$passwords = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query =  "INSERT INTO account (username, passwords, email) VALUES ('$username', 
'$passwords', '$email')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $username;
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors from the `mysql_query` statement...try adding `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of that line. Alternatively you can echo the query and copy and paste it into phpMyAdmin or the MySQL console to make sure the query itself is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are for strings; backticks are for table and column name escaping

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO account (username, passwords, email) 
VALUES ('$username', '$passwords', '$email')", $link);
```

So remove the quotes from the table and column names and add them to the values.

<sub>Please, [don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). 
They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
Learn about **Prepared Statements** instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for a quick overview how to do it and why it is so important.</sub>

Comment: Sadly this didn't work but I have turned on the error reporting thanks to another comment below and I'm currently working on the issue! Thank you so much for your quick response!

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource     given in /var/www/register.php on line 16

Comment: You need to switch the parameters. First comes the query and then the connection. See my update.

Comment: Your edit would have worked as well. Since I've got it to work with the secondary update I put I've decided to leave it like that lol. Thank you once again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotations around account or use ` around account

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

First, you should not use PHP's `mysql` for new development... Read about [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), seriously! (Also, a great blog post for beginners: http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Second, if you *must* use `mysql`, and if PHP doesn't return any errors, you can utilize [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-error.php) to diagnose the problem.

P.S. Check for PHP errors using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',"On");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lines for error reporting. I've looked into mysqli but with the timeline I have right now it's not possible. Really do appreciate the quick response.